# How can I use regex to determine if a string includes one substring but not a different substring?

Tags: javascript, regex, debugging

I'm trying to find a regular expression that will tell me if a string includes one word but not another.

Basically, I need to find a way to return true for the following

`base?param1=value1&param2=value2`

but I want it to return false if any of the values (or really, any part of the strings contains `Debug`

So for example:

```
collect?e=checkout --> true
collect?e=Debug --> false
```

I need this as a clean regular expression as I'm just trying to use it in Chrome network filter.

I tried 
/(collect).+(?!Debug.)*/ but that doesnt work

The closest I can get is simply /(?!Debug.)*/ which omits anything with Debug in the string but does not limit it to those strings that contain the word "collect"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get your negative lookahead to work in the way you would like by moving the ".+" so that it's after the "?!"

In other words, since you're trying to match the word collect when it isn't followed by the word Debug after any (non-zero) number of characters, you can get that with the following expression:

```
/collect(?!.+Debug).*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/(?<!Debug.*)collect(?!.*Debug)/
```

Basically, it's saying that you should only match `collect` if it doesn't follow a string containing `Debug` and if it isn't followed by a string containing `Debug`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `(collect).+(?!Debug.)` will not work as intended because you first match `collect` and then `.+` will match any char 1+ times until the end of the string.

Then when you are at the end, this assertion `(?!Debug.)` will be true because there is nothing at the right as you are at the end.

What you could dot is match `collect?e=` and then assert what is directly to the right is not Debug.

```
collect\?e=(?!Debug\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GfggyV/1)